# Laravel Not posting to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a bug in the code somewhere and I cant seem to find it , any help would be great. Its a simple form that stores to a DB.

The app is using laravel 5.2 and all that is needed is to collect data. when the submit button is hit on the form nothing!

route

```
Route::resource('/form' , 'PagesController');
```

controller only needs to indes, create and store , thats all the app needs to do.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Data;
use App\Http\Requests\DataRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    //Display Index
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('welcome');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view ('create');
    }

    //Store Articles from form
    public function store(DataRequest $request)
    {
        Data::create($request->all());
        return redirect('create')->with('message' , 'Form submitted');
    }


}
```

model uses a simple protected fields list and carbon to store timestamps

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Requests\DataRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Data extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'company',
        'addcomments',
        'published_at',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    //Get all published articles by date
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        $query->where('published_at' , '<=' , Carbon::now());
    }
    //Get all unpublished or future articles
    public function scopeUnpublished($query)
    {
        $query->where('published_at' , '>=' , Carbon::now());
    }
    // Set form to publish articles with a time and date in the Published_at field
    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' , $date);
    }
}
```

form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'form']) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('name' , 'Name:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('email' , 'EMail:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('email', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('phone' , 'Phone Number:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('phone', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('company' , 'Company:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('company', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('addcomments' , 'Additional Comments:') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('addcomments', null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Submit Now', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Does the page refresh at all, or does it somply do nothin when you press submiit? try putting a / in the url {!! Form::open(['url' => '/form']) !!}.

Comment: if you log out $request to the laravel log are you getting all the data you expect?

Comment: Are you sure this code works at all? You are using wrong namespaces for Data

Comment: @MinaAbadir I believe the namespace of Data file is fine... but in PagesController it is wrong.... @Morby... it should be `use App\Data` instead of `use Data`

Comment: @prateekkathal That's what I was saying, he is importing the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was what was mentioned in the comments

use DATA;

to

use App\DATA;

and a mixture of a few little front end tweaks

all sorted